# Validate date values in Meteor AutoForm SimpleSchema

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I have the following Schema:

```
Dates.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        max: 50
    },
    start: {
        type: Date,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
            }
        }
    },
    end: {
        type: Date,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

How can I validate that the `end` date is not before `start`? I am using MomentJS to handle date types, however my main problem is how I can access other attributes in the `custom` function.

For instance:

```
end: {
   type: Date,
   autoform: {
       afFieldInput: {
           type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
       }
   },
   custom: function() {
       if (moment(this.value).isBefore(start)) return "badDate";
   }
}
```

How can I access `start`?

Furthermore, how can I validate if the `start` + `end` date combination is **unique**, meaning there is no document saved in my database which has the exact same `start` and `end` date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inter-field communication, you can do:

```
end: {
  type: Date,
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
    }
  },
  custom: function() {
    // get a reference to the fields
    var start = this.field('start');
    var end = this;
    // Make sure the fields are set so that .value is not undefined
    if (start.isSet && end.isSet) {
      if (moment(end.value).isBefore(start.value)) return "badDate";
    }
  }
}
```

You should of course declare the `badDate` error first

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
  badDate: 'End date must be after the start date.',
  notDateCombinationUnique: 'The start/end date combination must be unique'
})
```

Regarding the uniqueness, first of all simple schema itself does not provide uniqueness check. You should add `aldeed:collection2` for that.

Furthermore, collection2 is capable of checking only a single field uniqueness. To accomplish compound indexes, you should use the `ensureIndex` syntax

```
Dates._ensureIndex( { start: 1, end: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Even after this, you will not be able to see the error from this compound index on your form because autoform needs to be aware that such error is existing.

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  NewDatesForm: { // Use whatever name you have given your form
    before: {
      method: function(doc) {
        var form = this;
        // clear the error that gets added on the previous error so the form can proceed the second time
        form.removeStickyValidationError('start');
        return doc;
      }
    },
    onSuccess: function(operation, result, template) {
      if (result) {
        // do whatever you want if the form submission is successful;
      }
    },
    onError: function(operation, error) {
      var form = this;
      if (error) {

        if (error.reason && error.reason.indexOf('duplicate key error')) {
          // We add this error to the first field so it shows up there
          form.addStickyValidationError('start', 'notDateCombinationUnique'); // of course you have added this message to your definition earlier on
          AutoForm.validateField(form.formId, 'start');
        }

      }
    }
  }
});
```